# Can I have two independent Spyder consoles for two independent Python codes?

Tags: console, spyder

I have two independent Python codes, each one with its own inputs and outputs. 
I would like to have two IPython consoles and two Variable Explorers, each one associated to one of the two codes. In that way, I could switch back and forth between my two independent codes. I DON'T need to use results from one code to the other.

I thought I could do it by unchecking  "Use a single instance" option in "Tools > Prefences > General", but this doesnt seem to achieve what I want, I still see only one Python Console and one variable expolorer.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can open two consoles in the same Spyder instance by going to the menu

```
Consoles > New console
```

Each console is independent and has its own Variable Explorer view.

For additional isolation you can also go to the menu

```
Run > Configuration per file
```

and select the option called `Execute in a dedicated console`. That will execute each of your codes in the same console every time you run them (our default is to run code in the console that has focus at the moment).